# Tornado: how to send back cookies with ajax

Tags: ajax, cookies, authentication, tornado

I'm using Tornado to build a web server and Now I'm coding the login module: after doing login, user can send a message to the server.

My idea is as below:
When the user login successfully, the server will set a secure cookie: `self.set_secure_cookie("user", username, expires=time.time() + 60)`.

Then when the user sends a message to the server, the request should contain the cookie that the server just set to tell the server the identity of the user. If there is no cookie in the request, the server will redirect to the login page.

Now the problem is: the server can't get any cookie.

Login:
[image]

You can see that a cookie is set when user does login.

Then the browser tries to send a message to the server with ajax:

```
url: 'http://www.example.com/addcomment',
method: post,
crossDomain: true,
data: message,
processData: false,
cache: false
```

However, when the server tried to `self.get_secure_cookie("user")`, it gets a `None`, which means that the request doesn't send any cookie to the server.

I also add

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
```

to the ajax but it doesn't work either.

If ajax can't send any cookie to the server, how could I use the secure cookies of Tornado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,after set cookie you can **redirect** to  visit_page_url

```
self.set_secure_cookie
self.redirect(visit_page_url)
```

if you via chrome check redirect network request headers,you will find like this have **Cookie** field:
[image]